# How to slide a div with overlay effect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-slider

I'm trying to create a sliding menu, which will be usually hidden & display with a button click. I did this but currently the div pushing other contents of the page while coming out, so the other contents getting broken. Here is a live example of my work so far.

http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-lesson-951/0/2

But I would like to have the overlay effect like the one we see on msdn library site. How I can do that?

Comment: Not sure but I don't think your example works? Anyway, I think it sounds like a case of CSS `position`. Haha... if you click on 'get a hint' it even tells you what to do!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to me that in your CSS you should give the menu a position: absolute and a higer z-index if you want the other elements to stay where they are and have the menu be on top of them.

Comment: Thanks mate, It seems its working. Please allow me to test it a bit further & I will mark your answer as accepted. :)